# jQuery highlight button on scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, menu

So, I have this:

```
<div id="nav" class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <div class="nav_logo"></div><a href=""><span     class="nav">home</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1"><a href=""><span class="nav">services</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1"><a href=""><span class="nav">portfolio</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1"><a href=""><span class="nav">contacts</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the user starts scrolling the `#nav` becomes fixed and I need each span `class="nav"` to have added class `active` when the user is accordingly on that page.

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'll want is to match the href attribtue to the current window.location and see if it matchs, if it does, add your class.

basically :

```
var url = window.location.href;
$('.container').find('.nav').each(function(){
                var href = $(this).attr('href');
                if( href ===url || (href+"/") ===url)
                    {
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                    }
});
```